# Homomorphism between S4 and A4

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism

I'm asked to find a group G with a subgroup H such that there is no normal subgroup N of G which performs: G/N =~ H.
I thought of G=S4 and H=A4, because I don't think there is an homomorphism from S4 to A4, but that's only a gut-feeling.
Is it true? If it is, how do I prove such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed no such homomorphism. An easy way to check this is to write down the size-$2$ subgroups of $S_4$, take the quotient of $S_4$ by them, and then observe that you never get $A_4$.

Alternatively, it suffices to prove that no size-$2$ subgroup of $S_4$ is normal. This is obvious because any normal subgroup containing a transposition must contain all transpositions!

Comment: Why does the first method work? Why the fact that I never get A4 by taking the quotient by the size-2 subgroups implies I have no homomorphism?

Comment: In your question, you asked for $G,H$ so that there does not exist normal $N$ with $G/N \simeq H$. By the first isomorphism theorem, this is equivalent to having no surjective homomorphism $G \to H$. So while there are homomorphisms from $S_4$ to $A_4$, such as the map sending everything to the identity, there are no surjective ones.